# Excel VBA Paste 2D Array as Text Keeping Leading Zeros

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a 2D Array, and some of the elements are simply numbers with leading zeros. I want to paste the 2D array to excel and keep the leading zeros where they are, but excel keeps removing them.

My only thought it to somehow paste the array as text to keep the leading zeros but I can't quite figure it out.

Help?

```
Sub Tester()
Dim FinalArray(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
FinalArray(1, 1) = "Hello"
FinalArray(1, 2) = "0123"
FinalArray(2, 1) = "Tacos"
FinalArray(2, 2) = "0004"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(FinalArray, 1), UBound(FinalArray, 2)).Value = FinalArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Declare the array as string i.e. instead of `As Variant` use `As String`.

Comment: You can also format column 2 as text `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"` before you place the array.

Comment: I've found that the most fool-proof method is to wrap each value in quotes and turn them into a formula like `"=""Tacos"""` so that when it's inserted into excel, the cell has the formula `="Tacos"` and the displayed value is a String `Tacos`. You can loop through the array and apply this to each value. With values longer than 255 characters, you need to split them into joined strings like `"=""" & Part1 & """&""" & Part2 & """"`

Comment: I would assume you can just add a leading apostrophe. So something like `FinalArray(1, 2) = "'0123"`

Comment: Warcupine, this worked! Thanks